# Blank page when copy document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

When I copy document

```
var document = new Document();

    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
    document.Open();
    var cb = writer.DirectContent;
    var reader = new PdfReader(this_file_name);
    document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    document.NewPage();
    var page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
    document.CloseDocument();       writer.Close();
```

When I open new document - it's empty.
I try change pdf version and compression level - no results.
I can't use PdfStamper, bacause after copy document need insert some text and image.[this bad file](http://www.filedropper.com/72d3bab2-2cb0-4042-a600-1911bb2bd543)

Comment: Can you share a sample faulty result, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That PDF is a good example of why it is never a good idea to assume that `0,0` corresponds to the "lower left corner". PDFs are actually free to redefine their coordinate space as they see fit. That PDF has this specific entry for page 1:

```
/MediaBox   [0, -1693.08, 2396.52, 0]
```

This offsets the `y` parameter by 1693.08 units "downwards". Luckily this is pretty easy to fix. You're setting the page size correctly but you also want to use that page size's coordinates when placing the template:

```
var s = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, s.Left, s.Bottom);
```

Comment: +1 for the coordinate issue. When copying pages as-is (i.e. not scaling, skewing, etc), [`PdfCopy`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html) is often the better and easier option. `PdfCopy` will also take care of "document level" content, like annotations, that are linked to a copied page. [`PdfCopy` example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=123).

Comment: I have PageSize with the parameters: