# Extracting text from PDF with correct/sensible coordinates

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox

My company licenses both iTextSharp and PdfTools. Trying to figure out the root cause I built Apache's PdfBox: All show the same behavior, so rather than creating two support requests and a post on the PdfBox list I'm trying SO first for the general problem.

For a real world PDF (according to the document's properties it was created by "SAP NetWeaver 740") all extracted text coordinates are way off, while the content is fine. Across all the tools I listed above:

The page size (as in, mediabox and cropbox) is 842.0 x 595.0 - a portrait invoice. My default test word (all are off, but that's the one that caused my investigation) starts at roughly 80% in. All tools report the coordinates of that text with x=778 - outside of the page bounds. The y coordinate seems to be fine though. Probably related, the width is off (too wide by a large margin) while the height is again fine.

Now, maybe the PDF is broken in some way. But then again: The text is rendered fine of course. If I select the text in - say - Acrobat Reader, that works fine (i.e. the selection rectangle matches the text on the screen). And I *assume* that SAP generates rather bland/unsophisticated documents, tbh.

I guess my question boils down to: Under which circumstances would text appear to be outside of the page's boundaries? What might cause the horizontal position to be totally out of whack (and always too large)?

Comment: 842.0 x 595.0 would mean landscape. If possible, upload a PDF somewhere.

Comment: Today is a national holiday for most of the iText support engineers, but did you post the PDF to the iText support system? If so, I could take a look?

Comment: I assume the cause is that the origin of the page is not in the lower left corner but somewhere else. E.g. a 842.0 x 595.0 page may have its visible x coordinates between 8420 and 9262. To  allow verifying this, please share the PDF.

Comment: To add to mkl's comment, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33105431/231316) for a little more

Comment: Bruno, mkl: I didn't create a ticket so far and honestly I'm not sure how to share the PDF. Openly, here, is impossible - that's a real invoice of a customer (using out PdfTools tech in this case, I explored the results using iTextSharp and PdfBox to figure out if it's a problem with the doc or the librar[y|ies]). Will try to see if I can share it privately with iText support (-> Bruno). mkl: That sounds interesting, but then again: Wouldn't the Y coordinate be way off as well, if the origin moved?

Comment: *That sounds interesting, but then again: Wouldn't the Y coordinate be way off as well, if the origin moved?* - It *can* be but it does *not have to* be. The answer @Chris pointed to is about a PDF for which only the y coordinate would be off while the x coordinate is not.